# rebinning a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, bin, dynamic-rebinding

I've a question about rebinning a list of numbers, with a desired bin-width. It's basically what a frequency histogram does, but I don't want the plot, just the bin number and the number of occurrences for each bin.

So far I've already written some code that does what I want, but it's not very efficient. Given a list `a`, in order to rebin it with a bin-width equal to 3, I've written the following:

```
import os, sys, math
import numpy as np

# list of numbers
a = list(range(3000))

# number of entries
L = int(len(a))

# desired bin width
W = 3

# number of bins with width W
N = int(L/W)

# definition of new empty array
a_rebin = np.zeros((N, 2))

# cycles to populate the new rebinned array
for n in range(0,N):
    k = 0
    for i in range(0,L):
        if a[i] >= (W*n) and a[i] < (W+W*n):
            k = k+1
    a_rebin[n]=[W*n,k]

# print
print a_rebin
```

Now, this does exactly what I want, but I think it's not so smart, as it reads the whole list `N` times, with `N` number of bins. It's fine for small lists. But, as I have to deal with very large lists and rather small bin-widths, this translates into huge values of `N` and the whole process takes a very long time (hours...). Do you have any ideas to improve this code? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, your solution is:

> [[ 0.  3.]
>   [ 3.  3.]
>   [ 6.  3.]]

How you interpret this? The intervals are 0..2, 3..5, 6..8? I think you are missing something.

Using [numpy.histogram()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)

```
hist, bin_edges = numpy.histogram(a, bins=int(len(a)/W))
print(hist)
print(bin_edges)
```

**Output:**

> [3 3 4]
>   [ 0.  3.  6.  9.]

We have 4 values in bin_edges: 0, 3, 6 and 9. All but the last (righthand-most) bin is half-open. It means we have 3 intervals [0,3), [3,6) and [6,9] and we have 3, 3 and 4 elements in each bin. 
You can define your own bins.

```
import numpy
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
bins=[0,1,2]
hist, bin_edges = numpy.histogram(a, bins=bins)
print(hist)
print(bin_edges)
```

**Output:**

> [1 2]
>   [0 1 2]

Now you have 1 element in [0 ,1) and 2 elements in [1,2].

Comment: Mmm yes, my algorithm misses the last bin, but your solution merges together the last two bins, or so it seems. For [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] with a binwidth 3, I expect occurrences as [3,3,3,1], but you get [3,3,4]. If I choose a bindwith 5 I expect occurrences as [5,5], but this code gives me bin edges that I don't understand, [ 0.  4.5  9. ]... Sorry, I'm not very used to python...

Comment: We have 4 values in bin_edges: 0, 3, 6 and 9. All but the last (righthand-most) bin is half-open. It means we have 3 intervals [0,3), [3,6) and [6,9] and we have 3, 3 and 4 elements in each bin. You can define your own bins: [0,1,2] and now you have 1 element in [0 ,1) and 2 elements in [1,2]. OK now?

Answer (score -1):

Numpy has a method called [np.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) which does the work for you. It also scales pretty well.